# How to pass file path to dataprovider method

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

I have 2 Test method (@Test()) method , I need data from different file for these testcases and I use dataprovider in both testcases , how can my dataprovider read get file path for each testcase .

```
 @DataProvider(name = "dp")
      public Object[][] getData() throws FileNotFoundException {
          JsonArray array = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("src/test/resources/TestInputFiles/workspace/demo.json")).getAsJsonArray();
          Object[][] data = new Object[array.size()][1];
          for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
              data[i][0] = array.get(i);
          }
          return data;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the test method as parameter to the dataprovider. 
One of the options is that

1. Based on testname the file can be chosen.

Or

2. you can create a custom annotation for filename and annotate your tests with the annotation and then use the Method object above to retrieve the annotation value. This would help in case the number of testcases is more.